# TS2554: Expected X arguments, but got Y w/ function overloading

Tags: typescript

First, my functions:

```
function randIntIncl(max: number): number;
function randIntIncl(min: number, max?: number): number {
    if(max === undefined) {
        max = min;
        min = 0;
    }
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //The maximum is inclusive and the minimum is inclusive 
}
```

(credit [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random))

Called like:

```
randIntIncl(1,9999)
```

I get the error:

> TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 2.

I'm *guessing* the TypeScript is matching the first overload and then erroring out. What I don't get is why it doesn't try the 2nd overload? `9999` is clearly a number, so it should match, no?

I could simply omit the first overload and everything would work peachy because I made `max` optional anyway, but I put the overload there for documentation purposes. When called with one arg, that arg is the *max* not *min* as the 2nd overload suggests.

So my questions are:

1. Is there a way to make this work? Did I do something wrong?
2. Or is this "as designed" and I simply shouldn't create ambiguous overloads?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you have overload signatures, the signature of the actual function definition is the "implementation signature", which doesn't count as an overload signature.  If you want it to be an overload signature, you have to write it twice.  See the [handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads).

Comment: A more up to date link: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads

Answer (score -1):

```
const fn=(...rest:any){
 console.log(arguments)
}

fn(1);
fn(1,2);
fn('a',1,1);
```

if you want to overload, try this.

Comment: You've missed the point of the question... and also you didn't use overloads at all?